Some problems with handling Sign-in flow manually in Firebase
I'm trying to have my unity game build/client send a REST API request to my Firebase to sign in the user via OPEN ID (my game is using Epic Games Account to login). On Epic Account Login, the browser will return back to the unity game build and then the game client would send the REST API call to Firebase with the Epic Client Token. On Firebase side I'm assuming that I should be using this function: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/openid-connect?hl=en&authuser=1&_gl=1*zpc9mn*_ga*MTA5Njg0ODIwNC4xNzI4NjY0NjM5*_ga_CW55HF8NVT*MTcyOTcwNTE1MS4zOS4xLjE3Mjk3MDUxNzkuMzIuMC4w#manual
Problem is upon implementing it as a Firebase Cloud Function in Index.js as seen here:
const { signInWithCredential, OAuthProvider } = require("firebase/auth");
const express = require("express");
const { getAuth } = require("firebase-admin/auth");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const authMiddleware = require("./authMiddleware.js");
var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

const app = express();
app.use(express.json()); // Ensure you can parse JSON body
app.use(authMiddleware);

const provider = new OAuthProvider("https://api.epicgames.dev/epic/oauth/v2/.well-known/openid-configuration");

app.post('/signIn', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const token = req.body.epicClientIDToken;

    if (!token) {
      return res.status(400).send({ error: "Token is required" });
    }

    const credential = provider.credential({
      idToken: token, // Use token directly
    });

    const auth = getAuth(); // Get the auth instance
    const result = await signInWithCredential(auth, credential);
    
    const credentialFromResult = OAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
    const accessToken = credentialFromResult.accessToken;
    const idToken = credentialFromResult.idToken;
    
    console.log(accessToken + " | " + idToken);
    res.status(200).send({ accessToken, idToken });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error during signIn:", error);
    res.status(500).send({ error: error.message });
  }
});

// Export the app as a Cloud Function
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);

It is sending "Unauthorized" error back to the Client as response.
Here's the error from Firebase's error logs:
Error: No Firebase ID token was passed as a Bearer token in the Authorization header. Make sure you authorize your request by providing the following HTTP header: Authorization: Bearer <Firebase ID Token> or by passing a "__session" cookie.
    at entryFromArgs (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/logger/index.js:133:19)
    at Object.error (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/logger/index.js:120:11)
    at validateFirebaseIdToken (/workspace/authMiddleware.js:17:22)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:328:13)
    at /workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:286:9
    at Function.process_params (/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
    at next (/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
    at jsonParser (/workspace/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:104:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)

Need some advice. From the error it seems like I've implemented it wrongly as Firebase is treating the Sign-in request as a typical api request done by a user that has already signed-in and already have a bearer token.
